# ElasticSearch Boost filed and sort by date

Tags: java, spring, sorting, elasticsearch, solr-boost

I am trying to boost query by fields and then sort them by date :

```
        multiMatchQuery.fields(columnSortOrder());
        searchSourceBuilder.trackScores(true);
        searchSourceBuilder.sort(new ScoreSortBuilder().order(SortOrder.DESC));
        searchSourceBuilder.sort("updated_time",SortOrder.DESC);
```

When I execute it return result boost by column. I want to get result with combination of both **Highest Filed order sort by date**

**Boost Order**

```
Field_A^3
Field_B^2
Field_C^1
```

sample data:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "updated_time": "2020-01-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
    "field_A": "Slovakia beyond",
    "filed_B": "The properties in Slovakia are beyound...",
    "Field_C": "Once you fix the relevance then sorting should work correctly."
  }

  {
  "_source": {
    "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
    "field_A": "**beyond** filed_A",
    "filed_B": "The properties in Japan is high",
    "Field_C": "Test description for filed_A"
  }

    {
  "_score": 2.56865,
  "_source": {
    "updated_time": "2020-01-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
    "field_A": "Test filed_B",
    "filed_B": "**beyond** is search  term in filed_B",
    "Field_C": "Test description for filed_B"
  }

      {
  "_source": {
    "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
    "field_A": "Test filed_B",
    "filed_B": "**beyond** is search  term in filed_B Test for Feb",
    "Field_C": "Test description for filed_B test for Feb"
  }

     {
    "_source": {
    "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
    "field_A": "Search Term filed_C",
    "filed_B": " is the search term for lowest column",
    "Field_C": "**beyond** Test description for filed_C "
  }
```

**suppose search term is "beyond" If search term is found in [field_A,field_B,filed_C] Expected Result is:**

[first priority Field_A sort by date]

1. Slovakia beyond Jan 2020
2. beyond filed_A  Feb 2020

[second priority Field_B sort by date]

3. beyond is search  term in filed_B Jan 2020
4. beyond is search  term in filed_B Test for Feb 2020

[Third priority Field_C sort by date]

5. beyond Test description for filed_C Feb 2020

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: May you please update the answer with an example of queries for Field_A, Field_B, etc.? Is it a full-text match, or an exact match? May you please tell, if there is match in Field_A but its most recent `document_date` is 2018, should it be in the result set higher than `Field_B, 2020`?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev this is not exact match and yes you are right if match is find in Field_A it should be higher regardless of dates but if there are more than one match match find in Field_A, with dates ex (2018,2020,2019) then Field_A should be sort by date accordingly. I have added some sample date in question and with expected result
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_track_scores)

> When sorting on a field, scores are not computed. By setting track_scores to true, scores will still be computed and tracked.

So enable `track_scores` for your query.

[Java API](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.2.2/org/elasticsearch/search/builder/SearchSourceBuilder.html#trackScores-boolean-)

Use trackScores with parameterised variation.

And

When I try with sample data, sorting by score also required.

```
   {
     "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
     }
    }
```

Add this as first sort and then sort by DESC date. It works as below.

If search term is part of more than one field [`field1, field2, field3`], then combined score will be calculated.

Comment: @Val Would you please check this?

Comment: Yes I did tried but it did priorities by score but not by date still. What I want is actually if search term is found in [field1, field2, field3]  result should set on top  [field1] and sort by date after [filed2] sort by date and the [field3] sort by date as I defined filed boost 

[Field_A^3
Field_B^2
Field_C^1]. I do not want to sort result with combine scoring.

Comment: Could you please provide some example data where you are facing the priblem

Comment: I have added some sample data with expected result, actually the criteria is to boost column and then sort them by date. All match find in filed A should be the first but among each other it should be sort by date as well.

Comment: Could you please add mapping for the fields also?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it. There's a cleaner approach with several queries (using [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/search-multi-search.html)), and a more sophisticated approach with a single query (using [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)). Let me explain you how.

### Cleaner approach using `_msearch`

Simply put, [`_msearch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/search-multi-search.html) allows to make one HTTP request with several Elasticsearch queries in it. I would advise to split the initial query into several queries and sort them by date. This approach will be simpler because as I will show you later, fitting this into one query will require modification of scoring, which is not an easy thing to do.

You can also make several requests without usage of `_msearch`, whichever you see fit.

### Why other approaches didn't work?

You already know about simple score tuning via boosting some fields over others, like in this example [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#field-boost) query:

```
POST /myscores/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "beyond",
            "fields": ["field_A^3", "filed_B^2", "Field_C^1"]
        }
    }
}
```

This will simply take the score of the match times 3 if it is matched to `field_A`, times 2 if `filed_B`, etc.

Now, the score is just a real positive number, and it needs to represent where in the list of matched results should we place a particular document.

As you already tried, if you ask Elasticsearch to use `updated_time` as sorting measure, it will ignore the score from matching, which is not desired.

The suggestion of fellow [Gibbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833915/5095957) also didn't seem to work, because using sorting by `_score` and then by `updated_time` (or vice versa) was disregarding one or the other option.

### Is there a way to unite `_score` and `updated_time`?

There is, let's try to use `function_score`:

```
POST /myscores/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "beyond",
                    "fields": [
                        "field_A^3",
                        "filed_B^2",
                        "Field_C"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "score_mode": "max",     
            "boost_mode": "multiply", <=== 2
            "field_value_factor": {   <=== 1
                "field": "updated_time",   
                "factor": 0.00000000001,
                "missing": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) allows you to fine tune the score of the query.

We take `multi_match` query that we are already familiar with from the section above, and try to modify it.

First, we know that we want it to take into account `updated_time`. We use [`field_value_factor`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) as function to modify the score (point 1 in the query above).

Now, we tell it to multiply the value of `updated_time` and the score of the query - via setting `boost_mode` to `multiply` (point 2).

Executing this query will produce something like this:

```
"hits": [
  {
    ...
    "_score": 43.121338,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "**beyond** filed_A",
      "filed_B": "The properties in Japan is high",
      "Field_C": "Test description for filed_A"
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 43.048275,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-01-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Slovakia beyond",
      "filed_B": "The properties in Slovakia are beyound...",
      "Field_C": "Once you fix the relevance then sorting should work correctly."
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 29.028637,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-01-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Test filed_B",
      "filed_B": "**beyond** is search  term in filed_B",
      "Field_C": "Test description for filed_B"
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 24.44329,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Test filed_B",
      "filed_B": "**beyond** is search  term in filed_B Test for Feb",
      "Field_C": "Test description for filed_B test for Feb"
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 23.517717,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Search Term filed_C",
      "filed_B": " is the search term for lowest column",
      "Field_C": "**beyond** Test description for filed_C "
    }
  }
]
```

Notice that scores of `field_A` matches are close to each other, but a little bit away from those of `filed_B`.

Also notice that the order by `updated_time` is most recent first; we will address the reverse order now.

### How to use `updated_time` to sort in reverse order?

[`field_value_factor`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) allows to multiply the original value from the field by some factor.

Internally Elasticsearch stores dates as unix timestamps. It is an integer of 10 digits, which is literally ~10 orders of magnitude bigger than the score ES returned me. So I chose to make them of comparable order:

```
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "updated_time",   
                "factor": 0.00000000001,
                "missing": 1
            }
```

Now, this gives us an equivalent of `SORT BY updated_time DESC`:

```
Feb 2020
Jan 2020
```

But what if we need it to be `SORT BY updated_time ASC`?

```
Jan 2020
Feb 2020
```

We cannot multiply by a negative factor because scores in Elasticsearch have to be positive real numbers.

What we can do instead is to modify the original value with `1/x`, like here:

```
        "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "updated_time",
            "factor": 0.00000000001,
            "missing": 1,
            "modifier": "reciprocal"  <=== 1/x
        }
```

This will finally give us the order you asked for in the question:

```
"hits": [
  {
    ...
    "_score": 0.17285699,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-01-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Slovakia beyond",
      "filed_B": "The properties in Slovakia are beyound...",
      "Field_C": "Once you fix the relevance then sorting should work correctly."
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 0.1725641,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "**beyond** filed_A",
      "filed_B": "The properties in Japan is high",
      "Field_C": "Test description for filed_A"
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 0.116562225,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-01-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Test filed_B",
      "filed_B": "**beyond** is search  term in filed_B",
      "Field_C": "Test description for filed_B"
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 0.0978178,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Test filed_B",
      "filed_B": "**beyond** is search  term in filed_B Test for Feb",
      "Field_C": "Test description for filed_B test for Feb"
    }
  },
  {
    ...
    "_score": 0.09411382,
    "_source": {
      "updated_time": "2020-02-04T01:00:06.870000Z",
      "field_A": "Search Term filed_C",
      "filed_B": " is the search term for lowest column",
      "Field_C": "**beyond** Test description for filed_C "
    }
  }
```

### How to do it in Java?

Although I can't provide you with the ready code, I believe that you may start from [FunctionScoreBuilder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.7.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/functionscore/FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.html) and try to integrate it with your existing code.

---

Hope this helps!